# Data Loading on Combobox except current logging user

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, combobox, ext.net

I am going load Employee Name from Employee table in combobox that I have done. But I want load the all employee name except the current logging employee name. For eg. X employee already logging with his personal page and he want to load the name of others employee in a combobox.

I have no idea how to do it, I am using ext.net combobox control and linq with asp.net(c#).
Your small sample/logic will help more.

Thank You.

Here is my Code.

BLL:
TrainingManager

```
public static List<EEmployee> GetEmployeeName()
    {
        return PayrollDataContext.EEmployees.OrderBy(y => y.Name).ToList();
    }
```

DAL:
Linq to SQL Code attached

Web:
Employee.ascx

```
<ext:Combobox ID="cmbRecommendation" Width="250" LabelSeparator="" runat="server" DisplayField="Name"
                    FieldLabel="Ask for Recommendation from" ValueField="EmployeeId" QueryMode="Local" LabelAlign="Top">

                    <Store>
                        <ext:Store ID="Store1" runat="server">
                            <Model>
                                <ext:Model ID="Model1" runat="server">
                                    <Fields>
                                        <ext:ModelField Name="Name" Type="String" />
                                        <ext:ModelField Name="EmployeeId" Type="Int" />
                                    </Fields>
                                </ext:Model>
                            </Model>
                        </ext:Store>
                    </Store>
                </ext:Combobox>
```

Employee.ascx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!X.IsAjaxRequest)
        {
            cmbRecommendation.Store[0].DataSource = TrainingManager.GetEmployeeName();
            cmbRecommendation.Store[0].DataBind();
        }

    }
```

Note: Employee Name are displaying in combo as A B C and I want to display only A and C when logging with B.

Comment: can you show any of the code you tried?

Comment: I  have added my code

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the current employee from DataSource:

```
var data = TrainingManager.GetEmployeeName();
/* remove the current employee from the data list */
cmbRecommendation.Store[0].DataSource = data;
```

Or define an overloaded version of the GetEmployeeName method taking an employee's name to exclude.

```
cmbRecommendation.Store[0].DataSource = TrainingManager.GetEmployeeName("currentEmployeeName");
```

Comment: If the answer helps, could you, please, mark it as Answer?